# Read local .db file in C# WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am new to c#, how do I read local database file in C# WPF?

I have tried this tutorial: [Link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c#/#/).

But I can`t manage get it to work, where do I put .db file, can some one point me to good tutorial or show the right direction.

Comment: you might find this helpful http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/92af8085-e9e7-411b-9ab0-52ae0e62942c/

Comment: you might also want to look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869192/wpf-embedded-database-application

Comment: You can learn through this question [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345508/how-do-i-connect-to-a-sql-database-from-c)

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419164/how-can-i-bind-a-c-net-dataview-wpf-to-a-sqlite-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this;

```
string dbfile = "C:\\.....\\datasabename.db";
string connStr= "Data Source=" + dbfile  + ";Version=3;Synchronous=Off;UTF8Encoding=True;";

SQLiteConnection sqlConn= null;
sqlConn = new SQLiteConnection(connStr);
sqlConn.Open();
```